# Laravel form binding

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am using laravel form binding along with 
[jqBootstrapValidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/) . In order to successfuly have the validate the input fields, I must pass something like "required" (without quotes) in the tag . Can you please let me know how can I achieve this ? 
FYI .. the minlength works fine but the required does not work.

For example one of input elements currently looks as such

```
{{Form::text('username', null, array('class'=> 'form-control tip', 'data-toggle'=> 'tooltip', 'data-placement'=> 'bottom', 'title'=>'Enter your username that you have been using till now. This is a compulsory field.','placeholder'=>'Username ( must be filled )','minlength'=>'2'))}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't, take a look at the source code that builds the attributes:

```
protected function attributeElement($key, $value)
{
    if (is_numeric($key)) $key = $value;

    if ( ! is_null($value)) return $key.'="'.e($value).'"';
}
```

You'll always get a `<attribute>=<name>`, what you can test is to use it this way:

```
{{ Form::text('username', 
                null, 
                array(  'class'=> 'form-control tip', 
                        'data-toggle'=> 'tooltip', 
                        'data-placement'=> 'bottom', 
                        'title'=>'Enter your username that you have been using till now. This is a compulsory field.',
                        'placeholder'=>'Username ( must be filled )',
                        'minlength'=>'2',
                        0 => 'required'
                    )
            )
}}
```

It will build a tag

```
<... required="required" ...>
```

And it might work for jqBootstrapValidation.

Otherwise you'll have to create those inputs manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this with the HTML attributes required="required" and also required=""  works too.  Changing the example they provide and adding in the Laravel Blade tags gives

```
<form class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Type something</label>
    <div class="controls">

      {{ Form::text('name', null , array('required' => '')) }}

      <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  {{ Form::submit('submit')}}

</form>
```

This worked fine and produced the error "This is required".  I swapped in your form field and added in the

```
'required' => ''
```

to the end of your attribute array and that too worked just fine.  Alternatively you could instead add in

```
'required' => 'required'
```

as jqBootstrapValidation picks up either.  Good luck.